# How do I add my own ROM to MAME?

Tags: linux, emulator, rom

I have a ROM dumped from an Apple //e, and I'd like to use it with [MAME](http://mamedev.org/) in Linux (I'm running Debian). However, it's not clear from the manual how I could do that. it seems I can put ROMS on `~/mame/roms`, but when I start MAME, it doesn't let me use those.

I have this ROM image, and I also have a couple of disk images (can I use those with MAME?)

Where can I find simple instructions on how to start an Apple //e with MAME? If it's possible to start directly from the command line, it would be even better!

I tried to identify my dumped ROM, and MAME says it doesn't match anything it knows (I'd expect that, since each clone's ROM will be different, I suppose).

```
$ mame -remident apple2e.rom
apple2e.rom         NO MATCH
No roms matched.
```

(the file `apple2e.rom` is in MAME's ROMs path, I believe, since it is in `~/mame/roms`)

Comment: How exactly did you get/dump the ROM?  Have you verified the ROM using MAME's `-verifyroms`?

Comment: a friend dumped from my old Apple //e clone (I don't have an EPROM reader/writer). MAME's `-verifyroms` will give me a list of Apple ROMS (besides mine), but none ara available when I start the emulator.

Comment: I don't think of MAME as being the first choice in Apple //e emulation, but I haven't been following the emulation community lately. Why'd you choose MAME for this task?

Comment: I'm actually been looking for an easy to use emulator to put on a Raspberry Pi (and use it as if it was my computer from 20 years ago). I thought MAME could be a good choice. Most Apple //e emulators have one problem or another; there doesn't seem to be a simple and robust one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because MAME is pre-release software. https://meta.superuser.com/q/13276/11116

Comment: **Note to close voters:** I found no evidence that this is pre-release software. It has had numerous official major releases; in fact there was another stable release in July of this year, and  Google ported MAME to Native Client 6 yrs ago, allowing MAME to run inside Chrome.  The close vote appears to be a case of trolling the site over a disagreement referenced in the linked Meta discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Do `mame -showconfig | less` and verify the ROM path matches where you put the file.

2) You can actually find all Apple ROMs for MAME on the internet, and you need a bunch of them (character generator, disk ROM, the monitor/BASIC ROM you dumped) in a specific format with a specific checksum. So it may be easier to use those ROMs instead of trying to massage your ROM into the format MAME expects (which I'd have to look up, too). Just putting a .zip file with several ROMs in it into the ROM directory also works.

3) You start mame with the name of the configuration you want, plus disk images, e.g.

```
mame apple2p -flop1 ~/games/apple/Bolo.dsk
```

for Apple II plus.

You can use other options to modify the configuration (cards in slots) as in `mame -sl[0-7] name_of_device`. `mame -lslot` shows available slot options (for all systems, not only Apple). `mame -ld apple2p` shows the default hardware for this configuration.

4) I totally agree a simple and robust Apple II emulator for Linux would be nice. :-)